# How to make sure that my Application connection to RabbitMQ is healthy?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-shovel

I am required to set up a keepalive endpoint to my web application (tomcat war).
The endpoint will be sampled periodically by my WAF to make sure that the app is healthy.

A healthy app means that the application is up and the communication to the RabbitMQ server (version 3.5.3 /spring-rabbit 1.4.5) is up and functional.

I will open some REST API to my WAF that will verify the connection status. 
Reading the documentation **I am quite lost on how to implement this functionally**.
I noticed some functionality that may help, but I am not sure:

1. Enable automatic recovery and use [RecoveryListener](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) and make sure that the last recovery did not fail.
2. Configure [HeartBeat](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) and figure out a way to be notified on “disrupted connections”
3. Create some Heath Queue and use a plugin like [Shovel](https://www.rabbitmq.com/distributed.html) to echo back the message, if I do not get any response I assume the queue is down

Answer (score 4):

You don't need anything special like shovel to implement a health check. Just create a health queue and send/receive to/from it.

If you are using Spring AMQP

```
rabbitTemplate.send("", "healthQueue", "foo");
String foo = rabbitTemplate.receive("healthQueue");
```

In addition, you can register a `ConnectionListener` with Spring AMQP's connection factory and you will be notified when the connection is created/closed.

Spring AMQP has had connection recovery from the beginning so the (relatively new) built-in auto recovery in the rabbitmq client is not used.

If you are not using Spring AMQP use `basicPublish` and `basicGet` on a channel to send/receive to/from a health queue.

Comment: Isn't it enough just to use `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.RabbitHealthIndicator` from Spring Boot or at least the same approach in non-boot project?

Comment: Yes, that would work too, to verify the connection is still good. Sending/receiving a message digs one level deeper.